# Calculating Score for JavaScript Quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a quiz, but I'm having trouble displaying the score.

I used radio buttons with values, either being 0 for wrong answers or 25 for the correct answer. I'm having trouble displaying the score. Here's what I have so far (HTML & Javascript).

```js
function resultScore() {
  result = 0;
  var ans1 = document.getElementById("q1").value;
  var ans2 = document.getElementById("q2").value;
  var ans3 = document.getElementById("q3").value;
  var ans4 = document.getElementById("q4").value;

  result += ans1 + ans2 + ans3 + ans4;



}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <h1> Quiz:</h1>
  <p id="question">Which is mechanical engineering?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q1" name="choice1" />Study, design and application of equipment, devices and systems which use electricity, electronics, and electromagnetism.</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q1" name="choice1" />Computer</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" id="q1" name="choice1" /> study that uses engineering physics, engineering mathematics, and materials science principles to design, analyze, manufacture, and maintain mechanical systems</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q1" name="choice1" />Study of wild animals</label>

  <p id="question">Who is Nikola Tesla?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" id="q2" name="choice2" />Serbian-American inventor, electrical engineer, mechanical engineer</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q2" name="choice2" />A method to join strings.</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q2" name="choice2" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q2" name="choice2" />Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

  <p id="question">Who developed de Laval nozzle?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q3" name="choice3" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" id="q3" name="choice3" />Gustaf de Laval</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q3" name="choice3" />Thomas Edison</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q3" name="choice3" />Alexander Graham Bell</label>

  <p id="question">Who is invented the first iridescent lightbulb?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q4" name="choice4" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q4" name="choice4" />Benjamin Franklin</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q4" name="choice4" />Claude Shannon</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" id="q4" name="choice4" />Thomas Edison</label>

  <button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="resultScore()">Submit</button>
  <h2 class="score" id="userScore"> Score: </h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

- You need to not submit - I use preventDefault and the submit event instead of click
- You need to convert the values to number (I use `+`)
- You need to loop over all checked radios
- You cannot have duplicate IDs

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loaded
  document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) { // when submitted
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    result = 0;
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".answer:checked")] // all checked radios
     .forEach(rad => result += +rad.value); // add their numeric value
    document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = result;
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <h1> Quiz:</h1>
  <p id="question">Which is mechanical engineering?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Study, design and application of equipment, devices and systems which use electricity, electronics, and electromagnetism.</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Computer</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice1" /> study that uses engineering physics, engineering mathematics, and materials science principles to design, analyze, manufacture, and maintain mechanical systems</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Study of wild animals</label>

  <p id="question">Who is Nikola Tesla?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice2" />Serbian-American inventor, electrical engineer, mechanical engineer</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice2" />A method to join strings.</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice2" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice2" />Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

  <p id="question">Who developed de Laval nozzle?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice3" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice3" />Gustaf de Laval</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice3" />Thomas Edison</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice3" />Alexander Graham Bell</label>

  <p id="question">Who is invented the first iridescent lightbulb?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice4" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice4" />Benjamin Franklin</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0"  name="choice4" />Claude Shannon</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice4" />Thomas Edison</label>

  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  <h2 class="score" id="userScore"> Score: </h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

In short:

1. Change the button type to `button` not `submit` as the latter refreshes the page and the js function is not executed.
2. Set the score content with the calculated result.
3. I've used `parseInt()` to parse the value from string to int before doing the calculation.

```js
function resultScore() {
  result = 0;
  var ans1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="choice1"]:checked')?document.querySelector('input[name="choice1"]:checked').value:0);
  var ans2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="choice2"]:checked')?document.querySelector('input[name="choice2"]:checked').value:0);
  var ans3 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="choice3"]:checked')?document.querySelector('input[name="choice3"]:checked').value:0);
  var ans4 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="choice4"]:checked')?document.querySelector('input[name="choice4"]:checked').value:0);

  result = ans1 + ans2 + ans3 + ans4;
  
  const score = document.querySelector(".score");
  score.innerHTML = `Score: ${result}`;

}
```

```html
<form class="form1">
  <h1> Quiz:</h1>
  <p class="question">Which is mechanical engineering?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Study, design and application of equipment, devices and systems which use electricity, electronics, and electromagnetism.</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Computer</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice1" /> study that uses engineering physics, engineering mathematics, and materials science principles to design, analyze, manufacture, and maintain mechanical systems</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Study of wild animals</label>

  <p class="question">Who is Nikola Tesla?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice2" />Serbian-American inventor, electrical engineer, mechanical engineer</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice2" />A method to join strings.</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice2" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice2" />Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

  <p class="question">Who developed de Laval nozzle?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice3" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice3" />Gustaf de Laval</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice3" />Thomas Edison</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice3" />Alexander Graham Bell</label>

  <p class="question">Who is invented the first iridescent lightbulb?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice4" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice4" />Benjamin Franklin</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice4" />Claude Shannon</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice4" />Thomas Edison</label>

  <button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="resultScore()">Submit</button>
  <h2 class="score" class="userScore"> Score: </h2>
```

**EDIT:**

4. I've changed multiple identical `id` attributes to classes and used the `name` attribute for selecting radio buttons.
5. Also, validation is added if the radios are not selected.

Comment: You need to edit some more. It gives errors if nothing is checked;)

Comment: Ah. But why not? See my working answer. In any case I removed my downvote

Comment: @mplungjan you are correct mate! I've added it. I like your answer better but it could be difficult for a beginner to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `querySelectorAll` to get your selected answers, `map` the `value` and convert to int using `parseInt` and then `reduce` to add.

presto, this will work with more or less questions.

```js
function resultScore() {

  const result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']:checked"))
                      .map(({ value }) => parseInt(value))
                      .reduce((a,v) => a+v, 0);
  console.log(result);
  document.querySelector('.score').innerHTML = result;

}
```

```html
  <h1> Quiz:</h1>
  <p id="question">Which is mechanical engineering?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q1" name="choice1" />Study, design and application of equipment, devices and systems which use electricity, electronics, and electromagnetism.</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q1" name="choice1" />Computer</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" id="q1" name="choice1" /> study that uses engineering physics, engineering mathematics, and materials science principles to design, analyze, manufacture, and maintain mechanical systems</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q1" name="choice1" />Study of wild animals</label>

  <p id="question">Who is Nikola Tesla?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" id="q2" name="choice2" />Serbian-American inventor, electrical engineer, mechanical engineer</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q2" name="choice2" />A method to join strings.</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q2" name="choice2" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q2" name="choice2" />Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

  <p id="question">Who developed de Laval nozzle?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q3" name="choice3" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" id="q3" name="choice3" />Gustaf de Laval</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q3" name="choice3" />Thomas Edison</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q3" name="choice3" />Alexander Graham Bell</label>

  <p id="question">Who is invented the first iridescent lightbulb?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q4" name="choice4" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q4" name="choice4" />Benjamin Franklin</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" id="q4" name="choice4" />Claude Shannon</label>
  <input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" id="q4" name="choice4" />Thomas Edison</label>

  <button onclick="resultScore()">Submit</button>
  <h2 class="score" id="userScore"> Score: </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Please don't use same ids for multiple elements. Instead use names to get all the radio elements; then loop and the see if the variable is checked and get the value.
- ParseInt the values to integers because while getting the values from the elements, they come as string.
- (Not relevant to calculation part) But as a good practice, please have start tag also if you are having the end tag (see label tag in your html).

Have fixed the solution for you

```js
function getSelectedValue(name) {
    var ele = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (ele[i].checked) {
            return parseInt(ele[i].value) || 0
        }
    }
    return 0 //This will avoid NaN condition incase nothing is selected
}
function resultScore() {
    result = 0;
    var ans1 = getSelectedValue("choice1");
    var ans2 = getSelectedValue("choice2");
    var ans3 = getSelectedValue("choice3");
    var ans4 = getSelectedValue("choice4");
    result += ans1 + ans2 + ans3 + ans4;
    document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = "Score: " + result
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <h1> Quiz:</h1>
  <p id="question">Which is mechanical engineering?</p>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Study, design and application of equipment, devices and systems which use electricity, electronics, and electromagnetism.</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Computer</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice1" /> study that uses engineering physics, engineering mathematics, and materials science principles to design, analyze, manufacture, and maintain mechanical systems</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice1" />Study of wild animals</label>

  <p id="question">Who is Nikola Tesla?</p>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice2" />Serbian-American inventor, electrical engineer, mechanical engineer</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice2" />A method to join strings.</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice2" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice2" />Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

  <p id="question">Who developed de Laval nozzle?</p>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice3" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice3" />Gustaf de Laval</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice3" />Thomas Edison</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice3" />Alexander Graham Bell</label>

  <p id="question">Who is invented the first iridescent lightbulb?</p>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice4" />Edith Clarke</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice4" />Benjamin Franklin</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="0" name="choice4" />Claude Shannon</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="answer" value="25" name="choice4" />Thomas Edison</label>

  <button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="resultScore()">Submit</button>
  <h2 class="score" id="userScore"> Score: </h2>
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any clarifications

Comment: Any specific reason to downvote the answer. It looks correct to me. Please explain!

Answer (score -1):

Just get the result dom element and update the content with new score

```
document.getElementById('userScore').innerHTML = `Score: ${result}`;
```